# Summation of N integers - confused about answer

Tags: probability, summation

$a_i$ and $a_j$ are variables with each variable having 1/2 probability of being either +1 or -1. So:

$\overline{a_i} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot1 + \frac{1}{2}\cdot(-1) = 0$

$\overline{a_i^2} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot(1)^2 + \frac{1}{2}\cdot(-1)^2 = 1$

So then;
$\overline{a_i a _j} = 1$ when $ i = j$ and $0$ when $i \not= j$

I have a summing equation that says this:
$\sum_{i,j}^N a_i e^{j\theta_i}a_j e^{j\theta_j} = \sum_{i=j}^N a_i^2 = \frac{N}{3}$

I have no clue how to get N/3 from that summation equation. Any help would be kindly appreciated.

EDIT: Since some people are confused, I will just post the entire question for clarity. I am specifically looking at the first half of part b, when I must find Beta. I will also post the solution provided by my professor. My professor doesn't believe in helping student understand the material given out, so I am on my own for figuring this out and that's why I posted here. Sorry if that is against the rules.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does the overline mean?  Is $e$ euler's constant? What are the $\theta_j$s?  And are is that supposed to be a $j$ (and not an $i$) in the $a_ie^{j\theta_i}$ term?

Comment: Something seems awry.  That final sum should clearly depend on $j$, for example.  Also, since $a_i^2=1$ the sum should clearly be $N-j+1$.

Comment: Really, nothing here makes sense.  Please edit for clarity.

Comment: @fleablood Yes that is euler's constant and yes sorry $\theta_i$ = $\theta_j$, I missed that originally.

Comment: @lulu I have edited with more information

Comment: But...this has no apparent connection to what you wrote.  You said the $a_i$ were discrete, with values $\pm 1$ with equal chance.  But now it appears that the $a_i$ are continuous, and uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. For the latter distribution I think you can convince yourself that the mean of each $a_i^2$ is $\frac 13$.

Comment: Sorry, could you walk me through how the mean of $a_i^2$ is 1/3?

Comment: It's just a uniform distribution!  $\int_0^1x^2dx=\frac 13$.